# Cloud9 IDE: Can't connect to my server on a custom port

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, wsgi, bottle, cloud9-ide

When using Cloud9 IDE I can't connect to my own server on ports that are allowed for custom apps on **c9users.io** `8080`, `8081` and `8082`.

It is a custom server with SSL functionality. When I host it elsewhere it is reachable, but on Cloud9 it displays **No data received** (`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`) everytime I try to access a resource on it. The [Python SSLWSGIRefServer](http://www.socouldanyone.com/2014/01/bottle-with-ssl.html) log does not show any connection attempt.

It might have to do something with the security settings or wrong path.

The path I'm currently using is shown here and my SSL certificate is custom generated.

```
https://{workspace}-{username}.c9users.io:{8080|8081|8082}/{path}
```

Here is the server that I'm trying to run:

```
import subprocess
from bottle import run, post, request, response, get, route, Bottle, ServerAdapter

def jsonp(request, jsonstring):
    if (request.query.callback):
        return "%s(%s)" % (request.query.callback, jsonstring)
    return jsonstring

@get('/<path>')
def process(path):
    response.content_type = 'jsonp'
    jsonstring = subprocess.check_output(['python',"scripts/"+path+'.py'],shell=False).rstrip('\n')
    return jsonp(request, jsonstring)

# copied from bottle. Only changes are to import ssl and wrap the socket
class SSLWSGIRefServer(ServerAdapter):
    def run(self, handler):
        from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server, WSGIRequestHandler
        import ssl
        if self.quiet:
            class QuietHandler(WSGIRequestHandler):
                def log_request(*args, **kw): pass
            self.options['handler_class'] = QuietHandler
        srv = make_server(self.host, self.port, handler, **self.options)
        srv.socket = ssl.wrap_socket (
         srv.socket,
         certfile='server.pem',  # path to certificate
         server_side=True)
        srv.serve_forever()

srv = SSLWSGIRefServer(host="0.0.0.0", port=8081)
run(server=srv)
```

Answer (score 1):

Cloud9 only supports ports 8080, 8081, and 8082 so you'll need to connect to one of those ports, not 8000.

For more info check out [Multiple Ports on Cloud9 IDE](https://docs.c9.io/docs/multiple-ports).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That reference manual seems to be already outdated and it redirects me from `c9.io` to `c9users.io`. And apparently on that address I still can't receive any output: `https://{workspace}-{username}.c9users.io:{8080|8081|8082}/{path}`

Comment: I'm not sure why this didn't work but glad it worked from the terminal. Thank you for pointing out the doc error, I have fixed it now.

Comment: It didn't work even with a simple Hello World example, so I switched to Django that works out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Django has a good alternative for the bottle server that eliminates all these problems and it has native support on Cloud 9 with [code examples](https://docs.c9.io/docs/django).

It takes seconds to start a server that supports Python and is scalable, just generate the code in Django admin and run this code:

`python manage.py runserver $IP:$PORT`

Comment: `runserver` isn't meant for production instances, and even if cloud9 is a dev environment I want it to be running as close to prod as possible